# Jquery tooltip Needs tweaking on .html() method when html styling/formatting code is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

This is the following JQ code which creates a tootip based on divname, trigger obj and the "message" to be displayed on tooltip, the problem here is when I pass multiple lines of message with formatting and styling tags included like `<p>`, `<li>` etc, its not rendering the tooltip. Not sure why... Even when I'm passing it through .html(). Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

"msg" string is like

`<p>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
</p>`

With styling and formatting included

```
function JQToolTip(toolTipDivName, trigObj, msg) {  
    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.className = "tooltip";
    overlay.id=toolTipDivName;
   $('body').append(overlay);
$("#"+toolTipDivName).html('<div class="AToolTip"><p align="left">'+msg+'</p></div>');
    $(trigObj).tooltip(
    {
      tip:"#"+toolTipDivName,
      track:true,delay:800,position:"bottomright",direction:'down'});           
 }
```

Comment: looks like you're missing fully closing a </p> tag.

Comment: I've edited it above. But thats not it.

Comment: when you say it's not rendering, is it appearing in the DOM and just not displaying on hover or it's not even appearing in the DOM?

Comment: Yes thats right.. If the "msg" is long which includes html tags, its not appearing in the DOM also

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#"+toolTipDivName).html('<div class="AToolTip"><p align="left">'+msg+'</p</div>');
```

Should be

```
  $("#"+toolTipDivName).html('<div class="AToolTip"><p align="left">'+msg+'</p></div>');
```

jQuery will often ignore code if a close carrot is not included `>`

+1 credited to cdlong.

Comment: I deleted that when editing on here. The actual code has the closing <> tag